# Failed to run the application on the phone (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I can not test my project created in Android Studio in my emulator and neither in my phone. I create a Maps_Activity and a fragmet_map, thinking that I would like to serve in my project, but I did not need it and I had to erase it, now I can not run my application on my phone or my emulator.

This is the **LogCat** when I run the application:

```
09-06 10:33:39.688 21767-21767/? E/Zygote: v2
09-06 10:33:39.689 21767-21767/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10272
    KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
09-06 10:33:39.690 21767-21767/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
09-06 10:33:39.691 21767-21767/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
09-06 10:33:39.692 21767-21767/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.julio.photogo 
09-06 10:33:39.701 21767-21767/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-06 10:33:39.747 21767-21767/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is enabled: try add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
09-06 10:33:39.810 21767-21767/com.example.julio.photogo I/ResourcesManager: updateResourcesForOpenThemeChange for Desktop mode 
09-06 10:33:40.175 21767-21767/com.example.julio.photogo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/lib/arm64
09-06 10:33:40.197 21767-21767/com.example.julio.photogo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-06 10:33:40.198 21767-21767/com.example.julio.photogo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.julio.photogo, PID: 21767
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.julio.photogo-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
09-06 10:33:40.258 21767-21767/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21767 SIG: 9
```

**Buld.Gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(app)** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.julio.photogo"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable false
        }
    }
}
//
//implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And keep all your service libraries in same latest version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```